# How put navigationBar backgroundImage without opacity in ios 7?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Hi I have navigationBar with image in ios 7 [xcode 5].
When I run my application my navigationBar auto be blur.

I want to chenge it to regular [no blur].

my code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I try add this code but the apps crash:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

What need I do to make all my navigation bars in app to regular?
thank

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard you can set it here [image]

If you need to set it in code use
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;`
in your `viewDidLoad`